# "In the workbench, set the Android SDK path in Mobile Application Builders preferences page"

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

IBM MobileFirst Plateform Test Workbench 8.7, gives error while uploading App from Mobile Client device ![enter image description here][1]:- "In the workbench, set the Android SDK path in Mobile Application Builders preferences page".

After connecting the mobile client (IBM Rational Test Workbench..) with the workbench in the eclipse. Then tried to upload the .APK application from the mobile to the workbench. The mobile client tries to upload, but gives the above error in mobile device.

Comment: Did you, in the workbench, set the Android SDK path in Mobile Application Builders preferences page?

Comment: Please let me know how to set the Android SDK path in " Mobile Application Builders preferences page". I am unable to go to the location.

Comment: I don't know either,but you should update your question. It's unclear what's you problem is.

Comment: anup, you do see that your image is not displayed..... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just able to resolve the issue by creating a Test Workbench project in eclipse workspace then  setting the Android SDK path in Mobile Application Builders preferences page for that Test project.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can download the SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
then you install and after install then should work